# trying to get property 'username' of non-object in home.php file

Tags: php

In my PHP project i want to get the logged in users data ,and After i logged in i am redirect to home.PHP page and i cant access $user data here is my code, any one who has experience before in this error please help me
in my user.PHP file

```
<?php

class User{
    public $db,$id;

    public function __construct(){
        $db = new DB;

        $this->db =  $db->connect();
        $this->id = $this->ID();
    }
    public function ID(){
        if($this->isLoggedIn()){
            return $_SESSION['id'];
        }
    }
    public function emailExist($email){
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT *FROM `users` WHERE `email`=:email ");
        $stmt->bindParam(":email",$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if (!empty($user)) {
            return $user;
        }else{
            return false;
        }


    }
    public function userData($id=''){
        $id = ((!empty($id)) ? '$id' : '$this->id');
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT *FROM `users` WHERE `id`=:id ");
        $stmt->bindParam(":id",$id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
         return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        
    }

    public function isLoggedIn(){
        return ((isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? true : false);
    }

}
```

and in my home.php

```
include_once 'session.php';
include_once 'connection.php';
include_once 'utilities.php';
include_once 'user.php';

if(!$userObj->isLoggedIn()){
    $userObj->redirect('index.php');
}
$user = $userObj->userData();

?>
<div>
                        <span class="font-medium select-none"><?php echo $user->username;?></span>
                    </div>
```

in my session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connection.php';
require 'user.php';

$userObj = new User;

define('BASE_URL','http://localhost:8081/insa/');
```

login.php

```
<?php
include_once 'session.php';
include_once 'connection.php';
include_once 'utilities.php';

if(isset($_POST['loginBtn'])){
    //array to hold errors
    $form_errors = array();

//validate
    $required_fields = array('username', 'password');
    $form_errors = array_merge($form_errors, check_empty_fields($required_fields));

    if(empty($form_errors)){

        //collect form data
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        //check if user exist in the database
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
        $statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $statement->execute(array(':username' => $user));

       while($row = $statement->fetch()){
           $id = $row['id'];
           $hashed_password = $row['password'];
           $username = $row['username'];

           if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
               $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
               $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
               header("location: home.php");
           }else{
               $result = "<p style='padding: 20px; color: red; border: 1px solid gray;'> Invalid username or password</p>";
           }
       }

    }else{
        if(count($form_errors) == 1){
            $result = "<p style='color: red;'>There was one error in the form </p>";
        }else{
            $result = "<p style='color: red;'>There were " .count($form_errors). " error in the form </p>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

here is my login.php file

Comment: Change `$id = ((!empty($id)) ? '$id' : '$this->id');` to `$id = $id ? $id : $this->id;`. If you put variables inside single quotes, it will read the variable name itself as a literal string, not the value. Read more [about strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in the manual to learn the difference between single and double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your $userObj contains FALSE, because the requested data could not be found. Try to `var_dump($userObj);` before you use it, to see what value it holds.

Comment: it is working like it return this "object(User)[2]
  public 'db' => 
    object(PDO)[4]
  public 'id' => string '3' (length=1)"

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say `var_dump($user);`. That's the object whose property you are looking up.

Comment: it returns false but i dont know why it is

Comment: i also add the login.php file

Comment: Try and `var_dump($id);` before `return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` in your User class. Check if a user with that id actually exists in the database.

Comment: it returns like "string '$this->id' (length=9)" but it exist in the database

Comment: Right. Can you see why that wouldn't work? `$id` contains the actual string `'$this->id'`, instead of the value of `$this->id`. Change `$id = ((!empty($id)) ? '$id' : '$this->id');` to `$id = ((!empty($id)) ? '$id' : $this->id);`